# Trying to disable a DOM created button given certain conditions

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I am trying to traverse a 4x4 grid where the first row is off limits.  Essentially this leaves us with a 3x4 grid.  I have 4 buttons that control direction (UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT).

If I am at location 4x2 (remember the first row should not be accessed as it is a header), and I press Right, nothing should happen as this would be the 5th spot.  If I am at 1x2, I shouldn't be able to push the left button either.  Finally, If I am anywhere on the bottom row (1x4,2x4,3x4, or 4x4), I should not be able to push the down arrow.

Unfortunately, I do not understand something as it goes right/left/down/up anyways.  This is what I tried:

```
down.addEventListener("click",function()
{   
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[cellCounter] != 3)
    {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[cellCounter] != 7)
        {
            if(document.getElementsByTagName("td")[cellCounter] != 11)
            {
                cellCounter += 4;
                document.getElementsByTagName("td")[cellCounter].style.border = "5px solid black";
                document.getElementsByTagName("td")[cellCounter-4].style.border = "1px solid black";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So I decided maybe making a function that would disable my up/left/right/down might be easier.  I decided that if cellNum == [0-3] that up could be disabled, if cellNum == [0,4,8] that left could be disabled, cellNum == [8-11] down and if cellNum == [3,7,11] that right could be disabled.

How do I implement this though?  How do I disable a button that doesn't have an id and how do I identify it?  You can look at my, mostly, working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/snelson26/GdAbJ/58/)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("td")` will always return a collection of DOM elements. Comparing a DOM element against a number will always be `false`. Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve there.

Comment: why disable? just check if the move would be "illegal" and ignore it if so. e.g. `if (new X position of object < 1) { ignore }`

Comment: *"How do I disable a button that doesn't have an id and how do I identify it?"* Elements can be "found" using the DOM's traversal APIs or CSS selectors.

Comment: I think it would be much cleaner to pass the movement delta to a 'move' function that will ignore all incorrect positions.

Comment: Is there a reason why your elements are not given ids?

Comment: @Marc B I ultimately wen't using your recommendation.  No need to disable, just ignore and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I am going to give you a sample how you can work it out. Give it a try and let us know how you are doing and what you have tried.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var up = document.getElementById('up');
var down = document.getElementById('down');

var ri = 1, ci = 0;

up.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   highlight(-1);
});

down.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   highlight(1);
});

function highlight(offset){
   
   if((ri + offset) > 0 && (ri + offset < table.rows.length)){
     table.rows[ri].cells[ci].style.background = 'initial';
     ri = ri + offset;
     table.rows[ri].cells[ci].style.background = '#A7A8A9';
     
   }
   else if((ri + offset) == 0){
     table.rows[1].cells[ci].style.background = '#A7A8A9';
   }
   else{
       table.rows[table.rows.length - 1].cells[ci].style.background = '#A7A8A9';
   }
}
```

```html
<table border='1' id='table'>
    <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 1,1</td><td>Cell 1,2</td><td>Cell 1,3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 2,1</td><td>Cell 2,2</td><td>Cell 2,3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell 3,1</td><td>Cell 3,3</td><td>Cell 3,3</td></tr>
</table>

<button id='up'>Up</button>
<button id='down'>Down</button>
```

Comment: I was unable to follow your example; I'm sorry.  I think collectively all of you have helped me though.  To be honest, I do not know how to give my elements ID's using DOM manipulation.

Comment: element.id = "your_id"